# iptables catches on DENY but not on ACCEPT place prior to it in the chain

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I have a weird problem with my iptables firewall: If I set two consecutive identical rules, the first is `ACCEPT` and the second is `DENY`, the incoming packet is denied (and logged as such).

How is it possible that the incoming packet is ignored by the first rule and caught by the second?

The fwbuilder view is here: 
[image]

Here is the `iptables` dump:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state     RELATED,ESTABLISHED
In_RULE_0  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
In_RULE_1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
In_RULE_0  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW
In_RULE_1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain In_RULE_0 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0     level 6 prefix "FW RULE 0 -- ACCEPT "
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain In_RULE_1 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            LOG flags 0 level 6 prefix "FW RULE 1 -- DENY "
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I also tried with the `ACCEPT` rule alone and it doesn’t catch.

The only difference I see is that the `DENY` rule is not `state NEW`, but it’s the same for the tens of firewalls I already configured and which are working okay.

Comment: For future reference, `iptables -S` (not -L nor -vnL) would provide the most readable and useful output. The -L output omits various details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it. It turns out my FW was perfectly good, but the virtual host was misconfigured. I didn't have any error but iptables was not allowed.
When I allowed it, the FW became operational... No wonder why we couldn't find the error at the iptables level...
Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that: 
A rule with the `-I` option of iptables puts a rule at the BEGINNING of the
list; A rule with the `-A` option puts a rule at the end of the list.

In your case: I think you might have used "-I" in both of your (near-identical) iptables rules, the second rule gets inserted at the beginning of the list
ahead of the first rule, and therefore you created a rule list with the rules in the order:

```
match -s x.x.x.x action DROP
match -s x.x.x.x action ACCEPT
```

Because your packet match both of those rules, the first one (`DROP`) in the order of the actual operational table(which resides in RAM) would take effect. The order have nothing to do with the order in your iptable config file.

Swap the order, and result will be differet.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't add them by hand. Furthermore, I tried with the ACCEPT rule alone and it still doesn't catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your iptables `In_RULE_0` only applies to NEW connections when you use `state NEW`.

It is also set on your FORWARD chain (packets through the server), not your INPUT chain (packets to the server).

How are you testing? Are you pinging a particular interface of the server?

Can you post the full output of:

```
iptables -vnL
```

Try the following rule to log traffic on the INPUT chain (pings to the server interface)

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -j In_RULE_0
```